# Ubuntu 20.04 UEFI installation - duty for creating secure boot password?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, uefi, password

I'd like to install Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual boot configuration with Windows 10 with UEFI standard.
Therefore, I've been asked to create a secure boot password when selecting the point with the third-party software. There it says, that instlaling third-party drivers would require a secure boot password.
However, I can deselect "Configure Secure Boot" without the point "Install third-party software" being deselected.

So is it possible to select the point with the third-party software without having to configure secure boot? Or will this lead to problems, i.e. that third-party apps won't be able to be installed afterwards?
Or would I be asked after the installation to create a password for installing third-party apps?

Kind regards,
X3nion

[image: Picture of installation window]

Comment: Disabling secure boot in bios/uefi does seem to make life easier to install graphics drivers.  As long as you don't do things that are not recommended(downloading from weird sites) after installing Ubuntu, should be safe with secure boot off.  If you want or need secure boot on, then need a password(always have secure boot off,so never saw that).  Turn off Win 10 fast boot option also, makes partitions easier for Ubuntu to see.

Comment: The issue is proprietary drivers like nVidia for video or Wi-Fi. Those need to be incorporated into kernel which must be signed. But since proprietary, Canonical cannot sign them, but a user can. I have secure boot off but no proprietary drivers required and have had no issues. You can turn UEFI Secure Boot off in UEFI settings, may be called "Windows" or "Other".

Comment: Mhm I installed Linux testwise besides Windows 10 by clicking "install third-party apps" and deselecting "Configure secure boot". I wasn't asked to type in a password, and Ubuntu seemed to have installed e.g. the nVidia graphics driver. Could it come to some trouble installing further third-party apps when I have not configured secured boot? Or will Ubuntu ask me to configure it if needed?

Comment: Possible problem with updating nvida driver if secure boot is on.  Think most linux users just turn secure boot off and be done with it.  Do you know if secure boot is on or off?

Comment: @crip659 Do you mean secure boot in the BIOS settings?

Comment: That is where secure boot settings are, depending on bios might need to set a bios password to change, if not done already.

Comment: @crip659 And now, having installed Ubuntu without setting secure boot password in Ubuntu, I can disable secure boot in the bios to update e.g. the graphics driver. However, what happens if I don‘t disable secure boot? Will the driver not install? Will Ubuntu notify me that there is a problem? So how do I get to know what there are problems with installing the drivers?

Comment: With secure boot on graphics update of driver will give problems.  Should get at least a notification that update failed.  As I said secure boot on, seems to give more problems than what it is worth, if you are careful what you download.  Windows and Ubuntu do not really need it for most people.

Comment: @crip659 Well okay. But what if the user for which I install the system watches movies on illegal websites using Ubuntu. Would it then be recommended to use safe boot?

Comment: If they download software and/or games from those sites, there could be a slight problem.  Videos are usually considered safer.  If person is an idiot then secure boot probably will not save them anyway.  Guy let his very young son on his tablet.  He is now on the hook to pay 19,000 pounds for a monster truck.

Comment: @crip659 Okay well, according to my opinion, the user shouldn‘t do that. But what about the secure book thing, when not having provided a password during the installation process: so there is the option to disable secure boot in bios to be able to install third party apps like devices. But is there an option to install those apps using secure boot on in BIOS, e.g. is there a possibility to create a secure boot password in Ubuntu afterwards?

Comment: Secure boot should be on or off completely(all the time).  Unknown to me if you will have another chance after, so if you want secure boot on, make a password for it now.  Write it down and don't lose it.

Comment: Well and when creating a password, is there a possibility to deactivate it afterwards? Or don‘t you know that?

Comment: Should be able to turn secure boot off afterwards.  Password just for Ubuntu to sign drivers.